# pointer to an array of pointes of c-style strings c++/cli

Tags: pointers, c++-cli, cstring

I couldn't find a reason for this problem.

The function ***getfruits*** returns a pointer to an array of pointes of c-style strings.
Main tries to access the c-style strings.

```
using namespace System;

#pragma managed
void getfruits(char ***list, int* count)
{
    char *txt[] = 
    {
        "apple",
        "orange",
        "pears",
        "banana",
    };
    *list = txt;
    *count = 4;
}

#pragma managed
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    char **lst; int cnt;    
    getfruits(&lst,&cnt);

    char *t; int i;
    String^ s;
    for (i=0; i<cnt; i++)
    {
        t = lst[i]; //t = <undefined value>
        s = gcnew String(t);
        Console::WriteLine("Fruit = {0}", s);
    };
    Console::ReadKey();

    return 0;
}
```

But it gets  instead of pointers to the c-style strings.

Eventually,

***An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in arraysandclasses.exe***

***Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.***

What's going wrong? Can somebody point out anything?  The code should simply compile  if copied and pasted. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've returned the address of a local array and used it. That's [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). `txt` has  automatic storage duration and gets destroyed as soon as you leave the `getfruit` function. But you keep a pointer to it and use it, but the pointed memory no longer contains a living object. I suggest that you should perhaps read a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).